# Angular - Unknown Provider after adding infinite scroll module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I am trying to use Angular's infinite scroll module and don't know why this error is coming up.

Here is the error that I have copied from chrome's console.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UploadProvider <- Upload <- MyCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=UploadProvider%20%3C-%20Upload%20%3C-%20MyCtrl
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4284
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4432)
    at angular.js:4289
    at getService (angular.js:4432)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4464)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9093)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8205)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7637)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7512)
```

Here is code from index.html

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
    <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance="addmore(offer.time_posted)">
        <div ng-repeat="offer in offerlist">{{offer.imageurl}}  {{offer.time_posted}}  {{offer.category}}  {{offer.offercode}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="controller13.js"></script>
<script src="ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Here is the code of Angular Controller

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['infinite-scroll']);
var imageurl;
var f;
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout','$http', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout, $http) {
    var testttt = '1279';
    var id = '123';
  var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('/fetchtweet', testttt).success(function(response) {
            console.log("I got the data I requested");
            $scope.offerlist = response;
            $scope.offer = "";
        });
    };
    refresh();    
    $scope.addmore = function(time_posted)
    {
        console.log(time_posted);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout','$http', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout, $http) {
```

In the above statement, you are inserting

```
Upload
```

as a service in angular. The provider / service seems to be missing.

Comment: I cannot accept your answer right now, I must wait for 6 more minutes.